# No results in the DataGrid after Oracle connection

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle11g

I tried to connect Oracle with C# but unfortunately without success. I am new to C# and WPF. Thanks for the help

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            String connectionString = "Data Source=DWH; User Id=readonly; Password=********;";
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SALARIES";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            dr.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception exp) { }
    }
```

Comment: At least you must 1) read items from data reader to some collection like `List<T>`, `ObservableCollection<T>`, etc; 2) add items to the grid, either via `ItemsSource` and data binding, or directly via `Items` (not recommended). Your current code neither reads data, nor filling grid with data.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the DataGrid, not even adding it to the UI, so what is your expectation?

Comment: @Yves: Did you define any DataGrid element in your XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**EDIT my code**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            String connectionString = "Data Source=DWH; User Id=readonly; Password=********;";
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SALARIES";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    dg.ItemsSource= dt.DefaultView;
                }
           con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exp) { }
    }
```

Comment: `DataTable`s? Are you serious?

Comment: Hey ubaldisney thank you very much for the reply. I tried this, but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all here is my solution

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            String connectionString = "Data Source=DWH; User Id=readonly; Password=*******;";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SALARIES";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```